# How do I get the @user from firebase user from Twitter

Tags: android, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to access the Twitter username after logging in via firebase to Twitter, but the .getDisplayName method returns the user's name, not the @
Any ideas?

I have tried this

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()
```

But it doesnt give me the @

Answer (score 1):

This information is available in [`AdditionalUserInfo.getUsername()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo), which you can get from the `AuthResult` when the user signs in.

It is not available from `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`.

Comment: And how do i inicializate it?

Comment: You call [`getPendingAuthResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getPendingAuthResult()) as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/twitter-login#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk) and then `authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo().getUsername()`.

Comment: I still dont understand the example, here is my code, how do i fix it?     
     https://gyazo.com/c5dbcda71977cd08b6ae21ca4e4b1468